# UK Tier Four Student Visa, Common Wealth Question Answered Incorrectly

Tags: united-kingdom, uk-visa

I submitted my application to the UK tier 4 student visa 1 day ago online. I am a Chinese national and currently reside in Canada as a student with a valid visa.

There is a question in the application form, asking me that:

> HAVE YOU BEEN ISSUED ANY VISA FOR THE UK, UK
>
> OVERSEAS TERRITORIES OR COMMONWEALTH
>
> COUNTRY IN THE LAST 10 YEARS?

Unfortunately I put a no there, before realizing that Canada is one of the common wealth country!

I listed Canada as a country that I have been within the past ten years in the following questions though. So I am actually contradicting myself a bit.

What should I do now? My visa appointment is next Wednesday, I have not yet submitted my passport. But I already paid the fees.

I am thinking about cancelling this application and reapply a new one. But I am not sure if this is a good idea. The UKVI is closed on weekends so there is really no way for me to verify with them now, until Monday.

What should I do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you disclosed your trip to Canada, you can credibly claim that your incorrect answer to the first question was due to your having overlooked the fact that Canada was part of the Commonwealth.  In other words, it was an innocent mistake.  Just explain at your first opportunity.